# When using jackknife to calculate cluster-robust standard errors, is centering at the full-sample estimator superior vs the mean of pseudovalues?

Tags: clustered-standard-errors, jackknife

Basing on the paper here:

[https://users.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/papers/tcauchy.html](https://users.ssc.wisc.edu/%7Ebhansen/papers/tcauchy.html)

both estimators suffer from the risk of downward bias. The paper defines the estimator of variance centering at the full-sample estimator $\hat{\beta}$ as $\hat{V_4}$, while the one centering at the mean of delete-one-sample estimators $\bar{\beta}$ (defined here: [Why are jackknife pseudovalues treated as independent?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/389943/159259)) as "jackknife pseudovalues" $\hat{V_3}$.
The paper then states that both estimators are prone to downward bias, and propose a new estimator, $\hat{V_5}$, that is presented as superior (for being never downward biased and not requiring the deletion of non-invertible clusters).
Can it be concluded that the lower distance/higher proximity of $\hat{V_4}$ to $\hat{V_5}$ (with respect to $\hat{V_3}$) makes it a superior estimator?
I would infer that from:

1. The equation (at the beginning of page 7): $\hat{V_5} \lt \hat{V 4} \lt \hat{V 3}$;
2. The fact that $\hat{V_5}$ is centered at $\hat{\beta}$ , as $\hat{V_4}$ and differently from $\hat{V_3}$;
3. The statement in the middle of page 7:

> When the sample satisfies clusterwise invertibility then the estimators $\hat{V_4}$ and $\hat{V_5}$ only differ by the degree-of-freedom correction (G −1)/G, which is typically inconsequential".